# How do I format this from str to byte-like object?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, byte

Ahoy, I'm having trouble with decoding these filenames (They're encoded as base64). I know they need to be byte-like objects, but I can't for the life of me make it so. Please help, much love.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./Files'):
    name, typeId = base64.b64decode(filename.replace('.png', '')).split('_!_')
```

Error:

```
name, typeId = base64.b64decode(filename.replace('.png', '')).split('_!_')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

You're probably going to get this error from two places:

1. `b64decode(filename.replace('.png', ''))`
   As you've mentioned, [`b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) expects a bytes-like object.
   But `filename` is a str and `filename.replace` will also return a str.
2. `.split('_!_')`
   Since [`b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) will return bytes, you also have to pass a bytes-like object to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split).

Try this:

```py
for fname in os.listdir('./Files'):
    fname_bytes = os.fsencode(fname.replace('.png', ''))
    dec = base64.b64decode(fname_bytes)
    parts = dec.split(b"_!_")
```

To solve 1., you can use `fsencode` as noted in the [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) docs:

> **Note:** To encode `str` filenames to bytes, use [`fsencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode).

To solve 2., you can prefix a "`b`" to the string to make it a [byte literal](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with `'b'` or `'B'`; they produce an instance of the `bytes` type instead of the str type.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Had some issues with the "_!_" being converted, but managed to get things working.